# Can not write Japanese characters by pandas in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to write data with Japanese characters to file CSV.
But CSV's  not correct Japanese characters

```py
def write_csv(columns, data):
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=columns)
df.to_csv("..\Report\Report.csv", encoding='utf-8')

write_csv(["法人番号", "法人名称", "法人名称カナ"], [])
```

and CSV:

[image: CSV File Content Attached]

`æ³•äººç•ªå·    æ³•äººåç§°  æ³•äººåç§°ã‚«ãƒŠ`

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Excel notoriously sucks at handling UTF-8 encoded CSVs. It's mostly likely Excel's problem, not Python's.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is OK, just tried it. I'm guessing the CSV file is good but you're trying to open it as **cp1252** instead of UTF-8.

What software are you using to open this CSV?

- If you're using Microsoft Excel, make sure to use "Import" instead of "Open" so that you can choose the encoding.
- With Google Sheets or LibreOffice it should Just Work.

---

Another possible explanation is that there's something wrong with your data in the first place. Here's how you can check that (I just took a few random characters from [this generator](http://generator.lorem-ipsum.info/_japanese)):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(['勘してろむ説彼ふて惑岐とや尊続セヲ狭題'])
df.to_csv('report.csv', encoding='utf-8')
```

Try opening that the same way. If it opens correctly but the other doesn't, the problem is in your code.

Answer (score 3):

For me **utf_8_sig** worked like a charm.

`df.to_csv("..\Report\Report.csv", encoding='utf_8_sig')`